# How to define embed video area height?

Tags: javascript, css, mediaelement.js

I'm using mediaelement.js to load a youtube video with custom CSS and it's working fine.

html

```
<div class="wrap">
  <video width="1049" height="590" id="yt_video" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <!-- Pseudo HTML5 -->
      <source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSQDk_zLkiM" />
  </video>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrap{width:100%;}
```

js

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
  success: function(mediaElement, domObject) {
      if (mediaElement.pluginType == 'flash') {
          mediaElement.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
              mediaElement.play();
              mediaElement.pause();
          }, false);
      }
  }
});
```

The problem:
I need that the video player have 100% width and max-height 590px, the embed video should have 590px too but the embed video is filling 100% too and it's height is overflowing the player area.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, don't try to set heights using "100%".  I would suggest calculating the required height using javascript and applying it that way, or setting a static pixel value.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow: hidden` to your CSS. That should "crop" the video down when it's taller than its containing div.

You could instead use `object-fit: fill` to stretch the image across the available space. This doesn't work in IE, however.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` will just cut the video content in half, it wont solve this problem. I need the video have 100% height of the `.wrap` area

Comment: So you want to stretch the video to cover the area?

Comment: Yes, also tried to use `embed{height:100%}` but it won't work

Comment: added info to the answer. the `object-fit` property could you help you out. It doesn't have full browser support though.